# Horizontal slide aka iOS but in HTML5/CSS/JS, no puglin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, html

I don't know how can I call this action/effect, but I'm looking to do that in a web app(non iOS app) and be able to do the same action just with html/js/css, without plugin if it's possible.

Image example:
[image]

It's the action of slide left and reveal the "more" and "delete" options.

Comment: Do you want fries with that?

Comment: Andrew, not thank you. I just wanted the name of it or examples that I can follow. I don't want that someone do it for me with fries.

Comment: Well you already described what you'll need to do. Capture a slide event with a gesture library, then from that event slide into view the more and trash elements for that particular item. Conceptually it is simple, but you'll need to use frameworks if you want to stay abstracted from the arcane world of gesture event registration and slide animations.